# How to display an image in a java applet in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, applet, bufferedimage

I'm having trouble displaying an image in an applet in eclipse. I'm wondering if there is any alternate way of doing this. I also want to know if there is a reliable online applet tester that displays an applet I made on the web. I'm following the oracle tutorials but they don't work. Here is my code:

Displaying class:

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;


public class usb extends Applet{
static BufferedImage background;
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Override
public void init() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try {
        URL url = new URL(getCodeBase(), "resources/usb_homescreen.png");
        background = ImageIO.read(url);
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
    setSize(1000,500);
    add(new goat());
}

}
```

Canvas class:

```
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;


public class goat extends Canvas {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
goat() {
    setSize(1000,500);
    setBackground(Color.white);
}

@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.paint(g);
    g.drawImage(usb.background, 0, 0, null);
}
}
```

Any ideas about what's wrong?

Comment: 1) Why code an applet?  If it is due to spec. by teacher, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should stop teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/). 2) Why AWT rather than Swing?  See this answer on [Swing extras over AWT](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6255978/418556) for many good reasons to abandon using AWT components.  If you need to support older AWT based APIs, see [Mixing Heavyweight and Lightweight Components](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/mixing-components-433992.html).

Comment: Is there a swing applet?

Comment: [`javax.swing.JApplet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JApplet.html) as seen since the introduction of Swing (1.2).  See also the example on the [applet tag info. page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/applet/info) here at SO.  It uses `JApplet`.

Answer (score 0):

Applets are executed in a special environment. When using them as plain objects, this environment is missing, i.e. the `init` method will never get called and the method `getCodeBase()` will not work. If you want to test an `Applet` there’s the program `appletviewer.exe` shipped with the JDK. It requires a HTML page containing an `<applet>` or `<object>` tag.

But there is also a way to instantiate an `Applet` within a stand-alone java application which will generate the required context. Given an `Applet` class “`MyApplet`” the necessary code looks like:

```
MyApplet applet=(MyApplet)java.beans.Beans.instantiate(
  MyApplet.class.getClassLoader(), MyApplet.class.getName());
System.out.println(applet.getCodeBase());//prove that the context is now there
// now you can use applet like a normal AWT/Swing component
```